# Can I reclaim points not claimed due to 200 cap following 'Serial upvoting reversal'?

Tags: support, up-votes

Yesterday it seems someone (likely a person, probably meaning well) upvoted a lot of my past answers. This ment that I hit the 200 point cap fairly soon and the upvotes (110 points worth) from answers i gave for that day didn't count.

Today i see a 170 point deduction with a 'Serial upvoting reversed' message, which I assume was automated? Which I'm happy to accept given the rules. However is there any way I can claim the 110 points i missed out on during the time the cap was in place because of these now removed serial upvotes? Feels like maybe a bug in the serial upvoting reversal logic?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Using the mod tools, I see

```
15 hours ago    moderator recalcs rep   InvalidateVotes old rep = 11820, new rep = 11690
```

So, although it looks like 170 points were reversed, you actually only lost (11820 - 11690) = 130 points, and I can see a string of 13 consecutive upvotes on your profile, so that's consistent.

The reputation history on your profile also shows this although in a (much!) more confusing way. The 40 point discrepancy is accounted for on the previous day. You got a 200 rep bounty, and then 240 reputation on top of it which wouldn't normally be possible because the daily cap is 200.

Hope this makes sense!